# How to set up Distributed Jmeter on AWS with Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter

I am trying to set up my [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) master/slave set up on AWS EC2 instances using windows. Out of the box integration didn't work (connection refused errors) and after some investigation I got to know that RMI communication only works if the machines are on same subnet (is this true?). I found [this](https://www.artofsoftwaredevelopment.com/performance/performance-testing-in-the-cloud-with-jmeter-aws) great article and I tried to follow it as is on windows (tried running ssh port forward tunneling via cygwin) but not have any luck. So I was hoping if someone already done this with Windows and can share their experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Out of the box integration didn't work (connection refused errors) and
>   after some investigation I got to know that RMI communication only
>   works if the machines are on same subnet (is this true?)

It is not necessary. Even if the machines are in a different subnet and addressable via the network, RMI should work. Here make sure the Security Groups and NACLs are properly set so that both EC2 instances can communicate with each other via the network.

You can check whether you can ping(For this you need to enable ICMP in your Security Groups and also make sure other needed ports are opened for RMI) from one EC2 instance to another. If the servers can communicate with each other, then you need to troubleshoot internal firewall configuration in windows EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

We have used https://testable.io/ AMI's from the marketplace. It takes care of all configuration and just needs to worry only about testing and the results.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B073JNTVKP

All our endpoints are secured to certain IP-ranges from testable.io. If you have internal, still you need to setup those security settings.

Hope it helps.